# How does `useEffect` run cleanup phase in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to implement debounce for searching in Reactjs using useEffect. It works but to be honest I don't really understand how it process

```
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('')
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('run useEffect')
        const getData = async () => {
            const {data, status} = await axios.get(`${url}${query}`)
            if(status === 200) setPosts(data.hits)
        } 
        const delay = setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('run fetch')
            getData()
        }, 2000)

        return () => {
            console.log('unmounted')
            clearTimeout(delay)
        }
    }, [query])
```

`query` is the value in the `input` tag that change by `onChange` event.
When I type string query, like 'redux' the order console following:

```
unmounted
run useEffect
unmounted
run useEffect
unmounted
run useEffect
unmounted
run useEffect
unmounted
run useEffect
run fetch
```

Can I know why it run the code in the return function first?

Comment: you should output the current value of `query` with the `console.log` to see which pairs belong together. so `console.log('run useEffect for ' + query)` and `console.log('unmounted for ' + query)` (btw: unmounted isn't correct. The component isn't unmounted here. It is just re-rendered because query changed and the useEffect cleanup callback for the previous render is run)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [My cleanup logic runs even though my component didn’t unmount](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#my-cleanup-logic-runs-even-though-my-component-didnt-unmount)

> The cleanup function runs not only during unmount, but before every re-render with changed dependencies.

The clean up function will run when the `deps` of `useEffect` hook changes.